# Where to find Identity Pool Id in Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Where is `Identity Pool` in `Cognito Console`. In the docs mentioned:

> IdentityPoolId
>
> An identity pool ID in the format REGION:GUID.

But I see only `Pool Id` and `Pool ARN` in the console. Which have different formats.

Comment: Nevermind, I looked at User Pools instead of Federated Identities.

Comment: Thanks, I had this same problem.  The documentation is for Cognito/federated identities is profuse but also terrible, and code samples are always out of date or off tangent.

Comment: You might as well expand that comment into an answer.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I can manage to get the `IdentityPooId` by aws cli:

```
aws cognito-identity list-identity-pools --max-results 10
```

The [command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cognito-identity/list-identity-pools.html) returns all of the Cognito identity pools registered for your account.

```
{
    "IdentityPools": [
        {
            "IdentityPoolId": "XX-XXXX-X:XXXXXXXX-XXXX-1234-abcd-1234567890ab",
            "IdentityPoolName": "<some custom name>"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 28):

You can find `Identity pool ID` if you select `Manage Federated Identities` on the page https://eu-west-1.console.aws.amazon.com/cognito/home?region=eu-west-1 and create an Federated Identity.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

If you've navigated to the dashboard, you can also pull the identity pool ID from the URL:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

After creating the user pool, If you did not create associated Identity pool, Create a new one (Identity pool) and while creating it, set it as below (or as per your needs)

[image]

Once you click create, click Allow on the following screen then you will see the identity pool id like below

[image]

If you already have one, The from Cognito main screen, click Manage Identity Pools, click on the pool you want to get its Id then from side menu click "Sample Code" you will see the same screen as in the above image.

Answer (score 3):

For folks working with AWS CloudFormation: The documentation for [AWS::Cognito::IdentityPool](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cognito-identitypool.html) says you can obtain the `IdentityPoolId` from the return value, via `Ref`:

> Return Values > Ref: When you pass the logical ID of this resource to the intrinsic Ref
> function, Ref returns the IdentityPoolId, such as
> us-east-2:0d01f4d7-1305-4408-b437-12345EXAMPLE.

With AWS CDK, you can output the `IdentityPoolId` this way (Python):

```
core.CfnOutput(self, id='IdentityPoolId', value=idp.ref)
```

Where `idp` is an instance of [CfnIdentityPool](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_cognito/CfnIdentityPool.html).

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this trying to fill out amplifyconfiguration.json.  Trying to figure out which identity pool was connect to the user pool.  In the management console, the name top under "User Pools | Federated Identities" is the name of the identity pool.  In Federated Identities, I can find the identity pool with the same name.  On the dashboard, I can see the user pool id listed as one of the authentication methods.  Grab the identity pool id out of the url or from the sample code like others have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You can find here: **Amazon Cognito** -> **Federated identities**:

[image]