# AWS Amplify MissingRequiredParameter userId error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-lex, aws-amplify, amplifyjs

I'm following the guide for starting with [Interactions](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/interactions). When I call the `send` method on Interactions, I get the following error:

> (node:27796) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MissingRequiredParameter: Missing required key 'userId' in params

It looks like Interactions is expecting a *userId* param, which in `@aws-amplify/interactions/lib/Providers/AWSLexProvider.js`, is supposed to be pulled from `credentials.identityId`. However, when I log `credentials`, it is type `SharedIniFileCredentials`, which does not have an `identityId` property [according to the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SharedIniFileCredentials.html).

From [reading the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityCredentials.html), `identityId` would have to be a Cognito user. `AWSLexProvider.js` makes no attempt at calling `CognitoIdentityCredentials` to get Cognito credentials.

Hence, **I am not sure where `identityId` is supposed to come from**.

My code is the example from the Amplify website:

```
import Amplify, { Interactions } from 'aws-amplify';
import aws_exports from './aws-exports';

Amplify.configure(aws_exports);

async function test() {
    let userInput = "I want to reserve a hotel for tonight";

    // Provide a bot name and user input
    const response = await Interactions.send("BookTrip", userInput);

    // Log chatbot response
    console.log (response['message']);
}

test();
```

So what am I missing here?

Comment: Having the same problem. Please let me know if you figured it out how to solve it yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue when adding a Bot which i creatred manually w/o using the full amplify setup, but just using the amplify React Frontend SDK to use the Chatbot-Component. Turned out that I used the wrong `identityPoolId`for Cognito Auth. When using the right one, which can be found as described here [where to find identity pool id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44481490/where-to-find-identity-pool-id-in-cognito#targetText=3%20Answers&targetText=The%20command%20returns%20all%20of,pools%20registered%20for%20your%20account.&targetText=You%20can%20find%20Identity%20pool,and%20create%20an%20Federated%20Identity.) in the cognito federeated identities section, the error disappeared and the bots started working. Additionally I assured that the `custom_auth_role` assigned to that identity pool has addtionally the following properties under actions:

```
            "Action": [
             ...
            "lex:PostContent",
            "lex:PostText"
        ],
```

This can be assgined in the IAM -> Roles Section for that role. Not sure if that is absolutely required though.

So finally this is what it looks like:

```
    //...all other React imports, etc
    import { ChatBot, withAuthenticator } from "aws-amplify-react";
    import Amplify, { Auth } from "aws-amplify";

    Amplify.configure({
         Auth: {
          identityPoolId: "eu-west-1:XX-XX-XX-XXX-XXX", //<-here the right Id needs to be set
          region: "eu-west-1",
          userPoolId: "eu-west-1_XXXXXX",
          userPoolWebClientId: "XXXXXX"
         },
         Interactions: {
          bots: {
           botNameAsInAwsConsole: {
            name: "someName",
            alias: "$LATEST",
            region: "eu-west-1"
           }
         }
        }
    });

    function App() {
     return (
      <ChatBot
        title="Demo Bot"
        theme={myTheme}
        botName="botNameAsInAwsConsole"
        welcomeMessage="Welcome, how can I help you today?"
        onComplete={handleComplete}
        clearOnComplete={true}
        conversationModeOn={false}
        voiceEnabled={false}
      />
  );
}

export default withAuthenticator(App, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've not used AWS Amplify before so this answer may not be the reason, but I have used Amazon Lex many times before. The UserId field that this is looking for may be the UserId parameter for the Lex PostText/PostContent request (please see below code)

From the [PostText Documentation:](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/LexRuntime.html#postText-property)

```
var params = {
  botAlias: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
  botName: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
  inputText: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
  userId: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required - THIS IS MISSING FROM YOUR EXAMPLE */
  requestAttributes: {
    '<String>': 'STRING_VALUE',
    /* '<String>': ... */
  },
  sessionAttributes: {
    '<String>': 'STRING_VALUE',
    /* '<String>': ... */
  }
};
lexruntime.postText(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

and the [PostContent Documentation:](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/LexRuntime.html#postContent-property)

```
var params = {
  botAlias: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
  botName: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
  contentType: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
  inputStream: new Buffer('...') || 'STRING_VALUE' || streamObject, /* required */
  userId: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required - THIS IS MISSING FROM YOUR EXAMPLE */
  accept: 'STRING_VALUE',
  requestAttributes: any /* This value will be JSON encoded on your behalf with JSON.stringify() */,
  sessionAttributes: any /* This value will be JSON encoded on your behalf with JSON.stringify() */
};
lexruntime.postContent(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

Now, like I said earlier, I've not used AWS Amplify before so I honestly am not sure, but hopefully this points you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You simply needs to login with a user that has "run AWS lex chatbot" permission role group/policy attached.