# Unhandled Rejection (MissingRequiredParameter): Missing required key 'userId' in params

Tags: reactjs, amazon-lex, aws-lex

I'm working on integration of react app with aws Lex Chatbot,
I have followed the manual process specified in this doc's - https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/interactions
And each and every-time, when i send a message, I'm getting triggered with following error message

> **ERROR**: Unhandled Rejection (MissingRequiredParameter): Missing required key **'userId'** in params

Can someone pls help me with this...

[image]

This is the way i'm sending my request

```
Amplify.configure({
    Auth: {
      identityPoolId: 'us-east-1:xxxx-xxxx',
      region: 'US_EAST_1',

    },
    Interactions: {
        bots: {
            "Chatbot": {
              "name": "Chatbot",
              "alias": "Bot1",
              "region": "US_EAST_1",

            },
          },

    }
  });
```

**Component**:

```
 <ChatBot
          title="My Bot"
          theme={myTheme}
          botName="Chatbot"
          welcomeMessage="Welcome, how can I help you today?"
        onComplete={this.handleComplete.bind(this)}
          clearOnComplete={true}
          conversationModeOn={true}
        />
```

Comment: Send `userId` with the request.

Comment: I'm not getting where to specify the userId, there is not specification of it in the mentioned documentation

Comment: Can you add how do you send the request?

Comment: I've added in the post

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AWS Amplify MissingRequiredParameter userId error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54148545/aws-amplify-missingrequiredparameter-userid-error)

Comment: No it didn't, I have seen it . I gave a valid Identify Pool Id.

Comment: Is your user logged in to a Cognito user pool tied to that identity pool when you call the handleComlete function? It looks like that is where the userId comes from.